# How do I loop through a table, search with that data, and then return search criteria and result to new table?

Tags: sql-server, loops, temp-tables, create-table

I have a set of records that need to be validated (searched) in a SQL table. I will call these ValData and SearchTable respectively. A colleague created a SQL query in which a record from the ValData can be copied and pasted in to a string variable, and then it is searched in the SearchTable. The best result from the SearchTable is returned. This works very well.

I want to automate this process. I loaded the ValData to SQL in a table like so: 
RowID INT, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Date1, Date2, TextDescription.

I want to loop through this set of data, by RowID, and then create a result table that is the ValData joined with the best match from the SearchTable. Again, I already have a query that does that portion. I just need the loop portion, and my SQL skills are virtually non-existent.

Suedo code would be:

```
DECLARE @SearchID INT = 1
DECLARE @MaxSearchID INT = 15000
DECLARE @FName VARCHAR(50) = ''
DECLARE @FName VARCHAR(50) = ''
etc...

WHILE @SearchID <= @MaxSearchID
BEGIN
   SET @FNAME = (SELECT [Fname] FROM ValData WHERE [RowID] = @SearchID)
   SET @LNAME = (SELECT [Lname] FROM ValData WHERE [RowID] = @SearchID)
   etc...

   Do colleague's query, and then insert(?) search criteria joined with the result from the SearchTable in to a temporary result table.
END

SELECT * FROM FinalResultTable;
```

My biggest lack of knowledge comes in how do I create a temporary result table that is ValData's fields + SearchTable's fields, and during the loop iterations how do I add one row at a time to this temporary result table that includes the ValData joined with the result from the SearchTable?

If it helps, I'm using/wanting to join all fields from ValData and all fields from SearchTable.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be far easier with a query like this..?

```
SELECT FNAME,
       LNAME
FROM ValData
WHERE (FName = @Fname
   OR LName = @Lname)
  AND RowID <= @MaxSearchID
ORDER BY RowID ASC;
```

There is literally no reason to use a `WHILE` other than to destroy performance of the query.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is possible that your answer is helpful, but I am not understanding it. The reason for the loop is to SET the variables using SELECT statement one row at a time. The variables are then used in a query which returns the best match from the SearchTable.

Comment: Why do you want to set the variables to those values though, @ScottDoom ? It seems we're missing the core of your SQL. a `WHILE` is normally a bad idea in an RDBMS

Comment: It might be possible that, instead of a loop, I need to essentially perform a join of the ValData with the "best match" from the SearchData (which is found using a query that I did not include in my question).

Answer (score 0):

With a bit more trial and error, I was able to answer what I was looking for (which, at its core, was creating a temp table and then inserting rows in to it).

```
CREATE TABLE #RESULTTABLE(
[feedname] VARCHAR(100),
...
[SCORE] INT,
[Max Score] INT,
[% Score] FLOAT(4),
[RowID] SMALLINT
)

SET @SearchID = 1
SET @MaxSearchID = (SELECT MAX([RowID]) FROM ValidationData

WHILE @SearchID <= @MaxSearchID
BEGIN

SET @FNAME = (SELECT [Fname] FROM ValidationData WHERE [RowID] = @SearchID)
...

--BEST MATCH QUERY HERE

--Select the "top" best match (order not guaranteed) in to the RESULTTABLE.
INSERT INTO #RESULTTABLE
SELECT TOP 1 *, @SearchID AS RowID
--INTO #RESULTTABLE 
FROM #TABLE3
WHERE [% Score] IN (SELECT MAX([% Score]) FROM #TABLE3)

--Drop temp tables that were created/used during best match query.
DROP TABLE #TABLE1
DROP TABLE #TABLE2
DROP TABLE #TABLE3

SET @SearchID = @SearchID + 1

END;

--Join the data that was validated (searched) to the results that were found.
SELECT *
FROM ValidationData vd
LEFT JOIN #RESULTTABLE rt ON rt.[RowID] = vd.[RowID]
ORDER BY vd.[RowID]

DROP TABLE #RESULTTABLE
```

I know this could be approved by doing a join, probably with the "BEST MATCH QUERY" as an inner query. I am just not that skilled yet. This takes a manual process which took hours upon hours and shortens it to just an hour or so.